# How to implement this higher order function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm a newbe in functional programming, and I'm trying to solve the following exercise;

---

Given the type

```
type Cont r a = (a -> r) -> r
```

Implement the following higher-order function

```
mapReader :: (a -> b) -> (Cont r a) -> Cont r b
```

---

The first step would be to simplify the types, which gives:

```
mapReader :: (a -> b) -> ((a -> r) -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r
```

Next, define the parameters that need to be provided in this function. These parameters are three functions so we get

```
mapReader :: (a -> b) -> ((a -> r) -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r
mapReader f g h = _1
```

From here, we can define the following types:

```
f :: a -> b
g :: (a -> r) -> r
h :: b -> r
_1 :: r
```

But now I'm stuck. There are two functions that result in r, and one of them contains another function (a -> r). How can I start defining r? Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: Did you already implement *simpler* higher order functions like `map`, `filter`, etc.? I think it might be worth first implementing these.

Comment: Why is this function called `mapReader`? That's quite surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

```
f :: a -> b
g :: (a -> r) -> r
h :: b -> r
```

and we need

```
_1 :: r
```

There are two ways we can make `r`: `g` and `h`.

Let's try using `h`. `h` takes an argument of type `b`. The only way to get one of those is using `f`. `f` takes an argument of type `a`, and ... we don't have any way to get one of those.

So now let's try using `g` instead:

```
mapReader f g h = g _2
```

We're told

```
_2 :: a -> r
```

Since we're constructing a function, we can apply lambda abstraction as usual:

```
mapReader f g h = g (\a -> _3)

a :: a
_3 :: r
```

But wait ... now we *have* an `a`, so we can go back to our first attempt:

```
mapReader f g h = g (\a -> h (f a))
```

Or, more compactly,

```
mapReader f g h = g (h . f)
```

---

What if instead of going back to the first attempt we did it the second way *again*?

```
mapReader' f g h =
  g (\a1 -> g (\a2 -> _4))

_4 :: r
```

You could go this way forever, but you could also stop here in two different ways:

```
mapReader2 f g h =
  g (\_ -> g (h . f))

mapReader3 f g h =
  g (\a1 -> g (\_ -> h (f a1)))
```

Oy! These are three *different* functions that all have the same type, and as shown this approach can be used to generate an infinite family of functions! How can you decide which one you want? You have to consider the intention. `g`'s argument is the continuation, so you want to compose a function with what you're passing `g`, not call `g` multiple times. So `mapReader` is the "correct" answer.

More precisely, `mapReader` is supposed to map morphisms for the continuation *functor*. That requires in particular that

```
mapReader id = id
```

That is,

```
mapReader id g h = g (h . id)
  = g h
```

That's unconditionally true for the correct definition, but not for any of the others.

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking at what you *can* do with the three arguments.

1. You can compose `f` and `h`: `h . f :: a -> r`.
2. You can apply `g` to `h . f`: `g (h . f) :: r`.

So you could simply say that `mapReader f g h = g (h . f)`. There's not enough information here to specify what `r` is; it depends entirely on what 
arguments `g` and `h` are given to `mapReader`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have

```
f ::  a -> b
h ::       b -> r
g :: (a ->      r) -> r
```

There's also the forward functional composition operator,

```
(>>>) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> r) -> (a -> r)
```

and the reversed application operator,

```
(&) :: t -> (t -> r) -> r
```

so that

```
f >>> h :: ......... -- what?
```

and

```
(f >>> h) & g :: ......... -- what else?
```

Can you come up with the definitions of `(>>>)` and `(&)`, just from their types?

---

Let me get you started on the first one.

```
(>>>) ::   (a -> b)    -> (b -> r)     -> (a  -> r)
```

means that

```
(>>>) (f :: a -> b)    :: (b -> r)     -> (a  -> r)
(>>>) (f :: a -> b) (g ::  b -> r)     :: (a  -> r)
(>>>) (f :: a -> b) (g ::  b -> r)  (x ::  a) :: r
```

So again we write them down

```
f :: a -> b
g ::      b -> r
x :: a
f x ::    b
g (f x) ::    ....
```

And that's that.

The most important rule that we used here, is

```
x   :: a
f   :: a -> r
f x ::      r
```